# Adding merge module in the case of a 64bit machine in Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit, setup-project, msvcrt, merge-module

I have a 32 bit application that depends on the Visual Studio 2010 C++ Runtime Redistributable.

However in one part of my application I need to do dll injection. For reason I don't really want to get into right now (just take my word for it). The injection code and the dll needs to be 64bit if the OS is 64bit and 32 bit if the OS is 64bit.

The problem is that code is dependent on on Visual Studio 2010 C++ Runtime Redistributable for 64bit in the case where the OS is 64bit. I would like only the 32bit Visual Studio 2010 C++ Runtime Redistributable to be installed on a 32 bit system and both the 32bit Visual Studio 2010 C++ Runtime Redistributable and the 64bit Visual Studio 2010 C++ Runtime Redistributable on a 64bit machine. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use static linking of the C++ runtimes for your few 64bit executables. That will be your best bet.